# Android MVC: Sending Messages to the Controller

Tags: android, model-view-controller, controller, handler

As shown in this blog [Mind The Robot](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/), the author suggests the controller gets it's messages from the View through a handler like so:

```
inboxHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("Controller Inbox"); // note you can also set a priority here
inboxHandlerThread.start();

    // ... some code omitted ...

inboxHandler = new Handler(inboxHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    Controller.this.handleMessage(msg);
  }
};

// from the View
controller.getHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Controller.HANDLE_UPDATE);
```

Because of the asynchronous of the sendMessage method and handler, I find this approach to be problematic in Android. If I'm to make a true controller, I need to delegate to the controller methods in the Activity like boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event). However, because handler is asynchronous I don't know if the KeyEvent was actually handled and can not return an appropriate value.

Instead I have chosen to pass my events from the View with just calling a method on the controller like

```
boolean sendMessage(int what);
boolean sendMessage(int what, Object data);
```

This way I can get an appropriate return value immediately from my controller and if the controller needs to handle these asynchronously it can transparently and I can still get a response back that the message will be handled either now or in the future.

**My Question:**
What advantage at all does the approach from MindTheRobot using

```
controller.getHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Controller.HANDLE_UPDATE);
```

have over something like

```
controller.sendMessage(Controller.HANDLE_UPDATE);
```

?

I don't see any advantages and to me it even seems like he is breaking encapsulation and exposing the internals of this class needlessly.

**EDIT:**
Okay, something easier. What approach do you guys take to sending messages from your Views to your Controllers?

Comment: For me this question is interesting too

Comment: I wrote a blog series answering these types of issues: http://www.therealjoshua.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Both views and models in MVC architecture should be written as standalone, independent components. The controller, on the other hand, might be (and, in practice, usually is) exposed to implementation details of both the view and the model.

This means that if you got a reference to the MVC controller in your MVC view (and I understand that you do) - your MVC is somewhat "broken". MVC view should know nothing about the controller which will be tied to it.

One way to go about this is to use [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) - make your controllers implement a predefined interface, while the views allow for observers to register for notifications.

However, I think that this method is a bit cumbersome, therefore I searched for an alternative. GreenRobot's [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is simply a treasure in this context - easy to use, fast and light. Give it a try.

I also created MVP tutorial/template application which demonstrate one of the approaches you could use. It uses the aforementioned EventBus for communication between components. The source code is here: https://github.com/techyourchance/android_mvc_template